# errors related to agenda

Tags: org-agenda, debugging, timestamped

```
#+startup: logdrawer 
#+SEQ_TODO: URGENT(u!) TODO(t!) SOMEDAY(s!) | DONE(d@) CANCEL(c@)

* Task

** TODO Pay bill
DEADLINE: <2023-02-20 Mon>
:LOGBOOK:
- State "TODO"       from              [2023-01-25 Wed 22:57]
:END:
```

If I position the cursor on the deadline's date and do [`M-x org-open-at-point`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Creating-Timestamps.html), I get this error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable org-agenda-buffer-name)
  org-follow-timestamp-link()
  org-open-at-point(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-open-at-point nil)
  call-interactively(org-open-at-point record nil)
  command-execute(org-open-at-point record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "org-open-at-point" "org-open-at-point")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "org-open-at-point" "org-open-at-point")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

If I do `M-x org-agenda-month-view`, I get this error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil)
  calendar-gregorian-from-absolute(nil)
  org-agenda-compute-starting-span(nil month nil)
  org-agenda-change-time-span(month nil)
  org-agenda-month-view(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-agenda-month-view nil)
  call-interactively(org-agenda-month-view record nil)
  command-execute(org-agenda-month-view record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "org-agenda-month-view" "org-agenda-month")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "org-agenda-month-view" "org-agenda-month")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

How to intepret these errors?

Comment: AFAICS, the only reason for `org-agenda-buffer-name` to be undefined (i.e. a `void` variable) is that `org-agenda` is not loaded.  Do `M-: (featurep 'org-agenda)` to check if the feature has been enabled. If not, `M-x load-library RET org-agenda`. But you should fix your init file to initialize Org mode properly.

Comment: Starting from `emacs -Q`, I cannot reproduce the second problem. If `org-agenda` is not loaded, then Emacs complains that `org-agenda-month-view` is undefined. If it is loaded, then the command does not raise an error: it just reports `No Org agenda currently displayed`.

Comment: @NickD " But you should fix your init file to initialize Org mode properly. " In this case, this means what?

Comment: It means that you should not have to explicitly load `org-agenda`: it's hard to be specific without knowing how you install/initialize Org mode, but ideally, you should have all the functions that you need available without having to load anything explicitly. In my case, e.g., my init file contains `(require 'org-loaddefs)` which is an auto-generated file that contains `autoload` definitions for everything. There is unfortunately no such facility for variables AFAIK, so this is not a complete solution, but it goes a long way towards solving such problems.

Comment: This is actually a bug: see https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/commit/?id=c45a05892 for the fix.

Comment: @NickD " it's hard to be specific without knowing how you install/initialize"→https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/75542/19777

Comment: I didn't look at it in detail, but other than "the definition has to precede the use" problem that the answer on that question identifies (which is a correct answer IMO), there is not much else going on there: just settings of options. In any case, as I mentioned above, *this* problem is not because of you doing something wrong (so my comment above about fixing your init file was off the mark): it is a bug In Org mode. The workaround I suggested (loading `org-agenda`) will carry you through until you can update your Org mode to pick up the fix.